# '+=' con not be applied to operands of type 'Student' and 'Student'

Tags: c#

I am just practicing some codes and I've faced with such error. don't know, why! perhaps someone could help me.

Problem: First I want to make students (Student Class) and add the students into a Classroom.

```
namespace CollectionTest
{

    class Student
    {
        private string name;
        private int age;

        public void add(string n, int a)
        {
            name += n;
            age += a;
        }
    }

    class Classroom
    {
        Student student;
        int roomNumber;

        public void Enrollment(Student list, int n)
        {
            student += list; //error ('+=' con not be applied to operands of type 'Student' and 'Student')
        }

    }



    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Johny Your `Classroom` class can save a reference to at most one `Student` object in the `Student student;` field. You want this field to be some kind of container like `ISet<Student>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add the Student to a List of Student, like this:

```
  class Classroom
    {
        List<Student> student = new List<Student>();
        int roomNumber;

        public void Enrollment(Student item, int n)
        {
            student.add(item);
        }

    }
```